# Can jaydata work with existing table or database?

Tags: jaydata

If I have table in WebSQL database with some data can jaydata work with it?

For example, I have such table:

```
var shortName = 'Del';
var version = '1.0';
var displayName = 'Del';
var maxSize = 65536;

db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
db.transaction(
    function(transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql(
            'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "main" ("name" VARCHAR NOT NULL , "last" DATETIME NOT NULL  DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE);'
            );
    }
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work for JayData

Yes, if you are following the naming conventions JayData uses you are able to use existing databases on a limited extent. Foreign keys and relations are likely a thing that will not work.